# Prove that for all positive integers $n, 9|(11^ n − 2 ^n )$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that for all positive integers $n, 9|(11^n − 2^n )$

So the base case would be

```
9 * k = (11*1 - 2 * 1)
9 * k = 9
k = 1 so yes
```

The inductive hypothesis would be the fact that $(11^n-2^n)$ is divisible by $9,$

So I thought then I would have to show that $(11^{(n+1)}-2^{(n+1)})$ is divisible by$ 9$

```
11^(n+1) - 2^(n+1)
11^(n) * 11^1 - 2^n * 2^1
(11-2) * (11^n-2^n)
9*(11^n-2^n)
```

Is this algebraically correct?

Comment: Under "the inductive hypothesis" it should be "is divisible by"

Comment: 11^(n+1) - 2^(n+1) ---- 11^(n) * 11^1 - 2^n * 2 ---- (11-2) * (11^n-2^n) ---- 9*(11^n-2^n)

Comment: In the comment this is very hard to read.  You should be able to edit it into your post (there should be a gray edit below the post) or post an answer to the question.  It is explicitly permitted to answer your own question.  This looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+...  +y^{n-1})$

Comment: Or, in congruence language $\ {\rm mod}\ x\!-\!y\!:\ x\equiv y\,\Rightarrow\,x^n\equiv y^n,\,$ cf. my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque I know that, thanks, just wanted to put it another way.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Can you factor $x^n-y^n$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Suppose that $\ \color{#c00}{11^n = 2^n\! + 9k}.\ $ Then

$\qquad \begin{eqnarray}  11^{n+1}&=\,&\quad 11\cdot \color{#c00}{11^n}\\ &=& (2\!+\!9)(\color{#c00}{2^n\!+9k})\\ &=&\quad 2^{n+1}\! + 9(\cdots)\end{eqnarray} $

which yields the induction step.

**Remark** $\ $ Essentially it is *congruence multiplication*, i.e.

$\qquad {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\,\ 11\equiv 2,\ 11^n\equiv 2^n \,\Rightarrow\, 11^{n+1}\equiv 2^{n+1}$

a special case of using the $\ $  [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) $\ \ A\equiv a,\ B\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\, AB\equiv ab\ $ in order to *inductively* prove the sought [Congruence Power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) $\ A\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, A^n\equiv a^n,\, $

Answer (score 1):

A quicker/non-inductive method is as $11 \equiv 2 \mod 9$, for all integers $n \geq 1$, $11^n \equiv 2^n \mod 9$, so $11^n - 2^n \equiv 0 \mod 9$ and hence $11^n - 2^n$ is divisible by $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $11^{n+1} - 2^{n+1} = 11(11^{n}-2^{n}) +2^{n}(11-2).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$11^{n+1}-2^{n+1}=11\cdot11^n-2\cdot2^n=$$
$$=9\cdot11^n+2\cdot11^n-2\cdot2^n=2(11^{n}-2^{n})+9\cdot11^n$$
First part is true from assumption and second part has 9 as a factor

Comment: As explained in my answer, this is a special case of [the proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) of the Congruence Product Rule, namely

Comment: $\begin{eqnarray} \\ \color{#0a0}{A-a\equiv 0}, &&\ \color{#c00}{B-b}&\color{#c00}\equiv& \color{#c00}0 &\,\Rightarrow\,& AB\ -\ ab &=\,& a(\color{#c00}{B\ -\ b}) &+& (\color{#0a0}{A-\,b})B &=\,& 0\\
\color{#0a0}{11-2\equiv 0}, && \color{#c00}{11^n\!-2^n}&\color{#c00}\equiv&\color{#c00} 0 &\,\Rightarrow\,& 11^{n+1}\!-2^{n+1}\! &=\,& 2(\color{#c00}{11^n-2^n})\! &+& (\color{#0a0}{11-2})11^n &\equiv\,& 0_{\phantom{I_I}} \\ \end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad\qquad  $   Note that the prior equality is precisely the same equality that you derived

Comment: I just gave a very elementary hint that helps to solve the problem posed. I agree that your solution is much more general, I do not know so much about congruence product rule.

Answer (score 0):

One of numerous possible approaches using Binomial theorem

$$11^n -2^n=(10+1)^n -\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j} =\\
\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}10^{n-j}-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j} \\
=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\left(10^{n-j}-1 \right) \equiv 0\,(mod\,9)$$

The identity $x^k-y^k=(x-y)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-j}y^j\right) \,\, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ has been used