# Why does one modulus disappear when modded by another modulus?

Tags: number-theory, logic, induction

I have the following equation:

```
( ((X + Y) mod 29) - Y) mod 29 = Z
```

However, This can also be written as:

```
((X + Y) - Y) mod 29 = Z
```

And achieve the same answer.
I have tested it mathematically, but I am not too sure what happens to the modulus since it is treated differently in comparison to a multiplication or division.

Is there any sort of a rule for this?

Thanks for all the help!

P.S Sorry if the formatting is wrong, I am new to posting Math questions.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/85660) answer summarizes some congruence rules, and I use it as a handy reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematicians prefer to define modular arithmetic in terms of congruence, rather than as an operation on natural numbers. We say that two integers $a$ and $b$ are "congruent" modulo $n$, and write $$a \equiv b \mod n$$ or $$a \cong b \mod n$$ when $n$ divides evenly into the difference $a-b$. To see how this connects to the operation way of understanding things that you're more familiar with, "$a \mod n$" is the smallest non-negative integer congruent to $a$ modulo $n$. For example, where you might be more familiar with the statement "$53 \mod 29 = 14$", we prefer to write $53 \equiv 14 \mod 29$, and $14$ doesn't really have any special significance here; it would be equally correct to write $53 \equiv 82 \mod 29$, or even $53 \equiv -15 \mod 29$.

Then the key fact at play for your question is the following theorem: if $a \equiv c \mod n$ and $b \equiv d \mod n$, then $a+b \equiv c+d\mod n$, $a-b \equiv c-d\mod n$, and $ab\equiv cd \mod n$.

This theorem says that to compute the sum, difference, or product of two numbers modulo $n$, one may substitute any other congruent number in place before computing the arithmetic operation. In particular, to compute $(X+Y)-Y$ modulo $29$, one may reduce $X+Y$ modulo $29$ before computing the difference, which is what you've observed. Mind you, $(X+Y)-Y = X$, so one could also compute this just by reducing $X$ modulo $29$ and calling it a day.

All of this is detailed in [the wikipedia page on modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks, it was alright to understand, the "a+b≡c+d mod n" made it a lot clearer, glad I know this theorem now, should come in handy for the future!

Answer (score 0):

```
( ((X + Y) mod 29) - Y) mod 29 =( (((X + Y) mod 29) mod 29) - Y mod 29)
```

Which is again:

```
( ((X + Y) mod 29) - Y mod 29 )
```

Therefore it results in

```
( (X + Y)  - Y) mod 29
```

Please refer http://nrich.maths.org/4350 for proofs of the steps used

Answer (score 0):

If we write
$$
\begin{align}
(X+Y)&=q\cdot 29+r\\
Y&=s\cdot 29+t
\end{align}
$$
we have on one hand
$$
\begin{align}
(X+Y)\text{ mod }{29}-Y&=r-Y\\
&=r-(s\cdot 29+t)\\
&=-s\cdot29+(r-t)
\end{align}
$$
which is congruent to $(r-t)$ mod $29$. On the other hand
$$
\begin{align}
(X+Y)-Y&=q\cdot29+r-(s\cdot 29+t)\\
&=(q-s)\cdot 29+(r-t)
\end{align}
$$
which is again congruent to $(r-t)$ mod $29$. The two  ways of calculating it differs by *which point* to disregard $q\cdot 29$ as it contributes with no remainder mod $29$.