# Reasoning about $z^n = x^m + y^m$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, exponentiation

Let $z,n,x,y,m$ be positive integers with $z \ge 5$ and $m \ge 3$ and $m$ odd.

Does it follow that:

- $z$ cannot be prime
- if $p \ge 5$ and $p | z$, then either $p > m$ or $p|m$

Here is my reasoning:

1. If $z$ is prime, then there are no solutions as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1153457/48606).
2. If $p | z$, $p$ doesn't divide $x$ or $y$ since if we assume $n$ is the lowest positive integer solution, we get a contradiction by the logic in step 1 if $p | xy$
3. If $p \le m$, then using [Lifting the Exponent](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Resources/Papers/LTE.pdf) (see Theorem 2), $p$ must divide both $x+y$ and $\dfrac{x^m + y^m}{x+y}$ and there is no solution unless $p | m$.

Am I correct?  Is there a mistake in my reasoning?  Is there a counter example?

---

Edit: added details to explain why LTE applies based on comments received.

---

Edit 2:  for this logic to be correct, each $p \ge 5$.

Comment: You can only use LTE when $m$ is odd (you didn't consider the parity), $p\mid x+y, p\nmid x,y$ (considering $p\neq 2$, which you haven't considered too, and you didn't consider $p\nmid x,y$, etc.). It is very unclear to me how you're using LTE here.

Comment: 1. Is a direct consequence of [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v16_n4.pdf). If $x\neq y$, then, since $m\ge 2$, $x^m+y^m$ has a prime divisor that does not divide $x+y$. Since $x+y$ also has a prime divisor, we know that $x^m+y^m$ has at least two prime divisors, so $z$ cannot be prime.

Comment: Forgot to say $m$ is odd but I had intended to say this since $x+y$ only divides $x^m + y^m$ when $m$ is odd.  Also $p$ doesn't divide $x$ or $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to Zsigmondy's theorem.  I'll read up on it.

Comment: The abc-conjecture is also related to equations such as this, although I see no straight forward application here.

Comment: I'm thinking you didn't quite state the problem correctly, since a counter-example is: n=1, x=2, y=2, m=3, z=16, p=2

Comment: You are right.  I think that other argument assumes that $p \ge 5$.  I thought I could switch that to $x \ge 5$ which is not correct.  I'll add that to the question.