# Prove $a^{(p-1)!}\equiv1 \pmod p$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If $p$ is prime and $a$ is a positive integer where $p\nmid a$, then prove $a^{(p-1)!}\equiv1 \pmod p$.

I know that Fermat's Little Theorem guarantees that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

I also know that $(p-1)! = (p-1)(p-2)(p-3)\ldots(2)(1).  $

Comment: At first glance, I thought this was going to be about the more interesting [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) (still a do-able exercise for someone considering the above): $p$ is prime $\iff (p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.  Alas.

Comment: It holds not only for exponent  e = $(p-1)!$ but for e =  *any* multiple of $p-1,\,$ by modular order reduction as explained in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2):

So now you have
$$
a^{(p-1)!} = \left(a^{p-1}\right)^{(p-2)!} \equiv 1 ^{(p-2)!} \pmod{p}
$$

Comment: @OP The final congruence holds by little Fermat and the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242). Note that this Power Rule only  works in the *base* of powers, not in the *exponents*. For the exponents we need to use modular *order* reduction as in the linked dupe.