# How to show that $5^{2m} ≡ 2^{2m} \mod 7$ , but not $5^{2m} ≡ -2^{2m} \mod 7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am not quite sure how to show that $5^{2m} ≡ 2^{2m} \bmod 7$ , but not $5^{2m} ≡ -2^{2m} \bmod 7$

My answers always show that $5^{2m} ≡ -2^{2m} \bmod 7$ , however, when I denote m with an actual number, it never works.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you post your answer. My guess is that you mixed $(-2)^{2m}$ with $-2^{2m}$

Comment: if this is true, how is 5^2m+1 ≡ -2^2m+1, if its not (-2)

Comment: We have $$5^{2m+1}\equiv (-2)^{2m+1}=-2^{2m+1}$$ because of the odd exponent.

Comment: just to clarify,  is -2^2m+1 = -(2^2m+1)?

Comment: Yes , it is. Without parantheses , the minus-sign applies after the power has been evaluated.

Comment: Please don't rollback improvements to your question, esp. those that remove notational ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

$$5^2\equiv2^2\pmod7$$

$$\implies(5^2)^m\equiv(2^2)^m$$ for any integer $m\ge0$

Now if $5^{2m}\equiv-2^{2m}\pmod7$

We need $2^{2m}\equiv-2^{2m}$

As $(2,7)=1,$ this implies $$1\equiv-1\pmod7\iff2\equiv0$$

Answer (score 1):

$\bmod 7\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{5\equiv -2}\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}5^{2m}\!\equiv (\color{#c00}{-2})^{2m}\!\equiv 2^{2m} := n,\,$ and $\,n\not\equiv -n,\,$ else $\,2n\equiv 0\overset{\large \times\ 4}\Longrightarrow n\equiv 0$

Comment: We applied the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/242) in the first arrow. Also note $\,n\equiv 0\Rightarrow 7\mid 2^{2m}\Rightarrow\ 7\mid 2\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.