# Does congruence mod k work for exponents?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For $\text{mod 5}$,

$[1] = \{\dotsc, -4, 1, 6, \dotsc\}$

So, we can write,

$$6\equiv1\ \text{(mod 5)}\tag{1}$$

Which means that I can substitute $1$ for $6$ (and vice versa) anywhere I see it $(\text{mod 5})$. So, consider the example below:

$$6^{719} \ \text{mod 5}$$

$$=1^{719} \ \text{mod 5}$$

$$=1\ \text{mod 5}$$

$$=1$$

[And this is the correct answer.](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/power-modulo?c=BDT&v=top:1,n:5,x:6,y:719)

Now, consider another example,

$$2^6\ \text{mod 5}$$

$$=2^1\ \text{mod 5}\ \ \text{[Using (1)]}$$

$$=2$$

However, this is a wrong answer. [The correct answer is 4](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/power-modulo?c=BDT&v=top:1,n:5,x:2,y:6). Why is substituting 1 for 6 not working in this case? Aren't they congruent to each other?

Comment: Short answer: $6 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ **doesn't** mean you can substitute $1$ for $6$ wherever you see it, so you're attempting to apply a rule that doesn't exist.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I see. So, what is the actual rule then?

Comment: Are you asking for the rule that applies in your example of $6^{719} \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ or are you asking for the rule that applies to exponents?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Both please

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/762060/694754) for the first question.  The second question is more involved, but [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/694754) covers the basic idea.  In your particular example, [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) would be sufficient to show $$2^6 \equiv 2^{6\operatorname{mod} 4} \pmod{5}$$

Comment: The correct rule for exponents is that you can reduce them mod any *period* $\,\color{#c00}n,\,$ i.e. $\,a^{\large\color{#c00}n}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large k}\equiv a^{\large k\bmod{\color{#c00}n}},\,$ see [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the first linked dupe. See the 2nd linked dupe for sums and products (i.e. polynomial expressions).